# How to make a div container unselectable using css2/js/html

Tags: html, css

I have tried  `::selection, -moz, -webkit, -o, node.setAttribute("unselectable", "on")` stuffs, but nothing worked. Anyone have any ideas about this?

Answer (score 0):

you may try to use `user-select:none;` with prefix : http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/

```
element {
  -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
  -o-user-select: none;       /* Opera */
  user-select: none;          /* regular */
}
```

test page  : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/owGfz